# How can I add the custom text fields under own plugin of WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a plugin I want a functionality of the text fields in admin panel options of the plugin in which I want to set the API key and URL and other things. So how can I add the three text fields in custom plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should create a admin menu page for the plugin options. 
 use the below code in your plugin page.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu_pages');
function my_menu_pages(){
    add_menu_page('My Page Title', 'My Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'my-menu', 'my_menu_output' );

}

function my-menu(){
 // code for displaying text areas for api key and url

 $html = 'Enter url : <input type="text" name="url" />';
 $html.= 'Enter Api key : <input type="text" name="api" />';
 $html.= '<input type="submit" value="save" name="save" />';

 echo $html;

}
```